# Programatically transfering documents from document library 

Tags: 2007

****i want to copy some doc items from one doc library to another document library programatically .I am able to achieve this on my server .
But the problem is ,when i want to transfer the doc items from one server to another server programatically . how can this be done****

Answer (score 1):

You may find this link useful if you want to copy it using web service.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8c112d85-1ab8-426b-be37-d010cf8647fe

Comment: the example is transfering from 1 site collection to another .
i need to transfer for 1 server to other server not the same servers.

Comment: @Getsmiles : the term "server" is not really useful... In SharePoint you should say "Farm". Because one server may be on the same farm...
Anyway, the link provided is correct. The 2 site collections don't necessary need to be on the same SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "one server to another server" you mean from one farm to another farm? In any case, consider using the Web Services for this.

Comment: can you please provide me some code for this ?

Comment: Take a look at http://spservices.codeplex.com